# Does foam have the ability to broaden the bandwidth of an antenna?

Tags: antenna

In some designs of aperture coupled patch antennas, a foam is used between the ground plane and the patch substrate.

What would be main logic using it there? The reason of using it may be that when feed line substrate and patch substrate are the same?

The design by side view like that;

Patch

Patch Substrate (Ep:3.55)

Foam

Ground plane(with aperture)

Feed line Substrate (Ep:3.55)

Feed line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foam is there because many foams can have a very low relative permittivity (essentially \$\epsilon_R = 1\$) as they are mostly filled with air. If you look at the fundamentals of patch antennas, you can see that in general, a larger distance between patch and ground plane result in a higher bandwidth.

One way to do this is to keep the patch further away from the ground plane with standoffs, and have air in between. The foam has similar electrical performance as air but unlike air, the foam can be used structurally as well, to keep a specific and precise distance between the patch and the feed/groundplane, and to ensure that nothing gets in between the patch and groundplane to interfere with the performance.

Comment: Thank you! In simulation, when I use air substrate between them and when I don't use, results differently come up. Why is that? Doesn't the blank already represent the air? When I use corner spacer in simulation ,results are same with when I don't use corner spacer.

Comment: The relative permittivity of air is (at microwave frequencies and below) virtually identical to that of free space. Hence, if you put air or free space in your simulator (which is what I assume your simulator will fill all non-defined material regions with), there will be no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the foam is that you need something structural to hold the metal/conductive patch elements.  Here's a complicated example.  I don't know how you would fabricate this without foam or some other non-conductive material.

[image]